# Oracle AQ - Queue Message replication

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-aq, oracle-golden-gate

We are upgrading our infrastructure and for that we are migrating from Oracle 10g to 11g.

We are using Oracle GoldenGate for data replication and it does not support replication of AQ messages as far as we know.

For Persistent queue, we have import/export option available. But there are some Buffered queues as well need to be replicated.

can anyone guide how we can avoid data loss in this situation.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: You may get better input from OTN Forum (Oracle Technology Network )

Answer (score 1):

`Oracle GoldenGate` can replicate only "logged" data change so it is impossible to replicate non-persistent queues by definition.

Other Oracle product that deals with queues replication is "Oracle Streams". If you unable to use Oracle Streams for that purpose; other solution might be complete replica of the AQ with another Oracle product "Oracle Coherence" - distributed cache, what is fault tolerant by definition and can do same job with of course code changes required.

It is not a problem to implement a queue on Oracle or any other vendor distributed cache. I believe that you may see significant performance improvement in this case.